# RHEL 8 OS compatibility with Apache Kafka 2.5.0

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Want to understand if Apache Kafka version 2.5.0 is compatible with RHEL 8 Operating system installed on the broker servers.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka's main dependency is on the JVM so if you are on 8 or 11 you should be fine. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#java
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#os

Comment: As per Confluent Kafka docs, support for RHEL 8.x  is not mentioned in the table. Pls refer below link:  https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/system-requirements.html

Comment: not supported by Confluent for the Confluent platform, correct. My link above is for OSS Kafka.